# What components of a DRAM (specifically LPDDR) memory do the power rails VDD1, VDD2 and VDDQ supply the power to?

Tags: power-supply, sdram, ddr

I'm working on a project that tries to understand the power consumption of LPDDR memory under different operating modes such as active, idle, self-refresh, deep-power-down mode. With my experimental setup (which i'm not at the liberty to discuss details about, sorry) I am able to measure the current drawn by the mentioned three power rails of the LPDDR memory (at mA granularity) under different operation modes. However, to understand the trends in my measurements I need to know what components of the DRAM memory are mapped to which power rail.
From reading the JEDEC standard, I do understand that VDD1 and VDD2 are "Core Power" supplies, and VDDQ is the I/O buffer supply, but I'm not entirely sure what exact components are supplied by each of the rails.

I would greatly appreciate any help.

P.S. My background is not in electrical engineering so please try to dumb-it-down.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These separated voltages were created with the evolution of the LPDDR standard.

LPDDR1 only had one voltage for all circuits (VDD) at 1.8 V.

LPDDR2 created a separate voltage for the data bus (VDDQ), the command/address bus (VDDCA) and internal circuits (VDD2) at 1.2 V, keeping VDD, now renamed to VDD1 at 1.8 V for the capacitor matrix/array/bank.

LPDDR3 kept the same voltages as LPDDR2.

LPDDR4 lowered VDDQ/VDD2 voltages to 1.1 V and removed VDDCA.

LPDDR4X lowered VDDQ to 0.6 V, keeping VDD2 at 1.1 V and VDD1 at 1.8 V.

LPDDR5 created two possible values for VDD2, 0.9 V (low) or 1.05 V (high), depending on the frequency the memory is running, also allowing VDDQ to be between 0.3 V and 0.5 V.

Take a look at this presentation: https://picture.iczhiku.com/resource/eetop/sHKLhyJrzATLaBmm.pdf

Specifically, take a look at pages 2 and 3.

For more in-depth understanding, look for the JEDEC PDFs regarding the specific version of LPDDR you want to study. Just Google the name of the files below and you will find them:

LPDDR: JESD209A.pdf
LPDDR2: JESD209-2F.pdf
LPDDR3: JESD209-3C.pdf
LPDDR4: JESD209-4D.pdf
LPDDR4X: JESD209-4-1A.pdf
LPDDR5: JESD209-5A.pdf

These documents are quite extensive, but you will find tables listing exactly what each voltage is used for.

BTW, the other answer posted is incorrect, as the person was talking about DDR3 and you asked about LPDDR, which is a different technology.

Answer (score 0):

To analyze the power consumed by the DDR3 die in different rails in different operating modes, you can use micron ddr3 power calculator xls. Here all you need to enter your requirement, such as

1. DRAM Density
2. Number of DQs per DRAM
3. Speed grade
4. DDR3 or DDR3L
5. Mode register bit
6. DDR3 memory controller
7. DDR3 die clock frequency

Power calculator xls throws you the exact power based on Data sheet test conditions and maximum limits, Power derated for system usage condition input and Total DRAM power consumed.

Also power consumption for different operating modes such as active, idle, self-refresh, deep-power-down mode appears immediately after entering your requirement.

This power calculation xls can be used for any vendor DDR3 die because all the DDR3 vendor follows JEDEC standard.
[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the reference! However, this tool (as you said) provides power based on data sheet values. But my issue is that I have performed actual current  measurements for all three power rails (VDD1, VDD2 and VDDQ) of a LPDDR3 module under various operating modes. And to understand the trends/variations in current measurements for each power rail, I believe that knowing which components each of them supply power to, will provide some insight.